# JavaFx Stop Moving Image Smudging Canvas

Tags: java, javafx

I'm trying to make a simple animated menu with images bouncing off around the screen but the images leave a trail where ever the move.

```
public void handle(long now) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        boolean intersectFlag = false;
        for(Letter l : letters){
            gameMenuGraphicsContext.drawImage(l.letterImage, l.letterRectangle.getX(), l.letterRectangle.getY());
            l.moveSimple();
        }       
    }};
```

Any idea on how to stop this happening?

Answer (score 0):

Think of the Canvas as a piece of paper onto which you are writing. If you don't erase anything explicitly everything will be visible what you have ever drawn to it. Actually you should reconsider your decision to use a Canvas at all. It is not very well suited for such kind of animations.

Answer (score 0):

As mipa stated, your problem is that the drawn image is never erased. To erase your canvas, use:

```
graphicsContext.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.getWidth(), canvas.getHeight());
```

To keep yourself from having to call the `clearRect`method each time you want to draw on the screen, one easy write-and-forget way is to combine the clearing and drawing into one method. You can even use a lambda expression to draw on the `canvas`, as in the following code:

```
private static void clearAndDraw(GraphicsContext gc, Consumer<GraphicsContext> draw) {
        gc.clearRect(0, 0, gc.getCanvas().getWidth(), gc.getCanvas().getHeight());
        draw.accept(gc);
    }

public void handle(long now) {
    //...
    for(Letter l : letters) {
    clearAndDraw(graphicsContext, gc -> gc.drawImage(l.letterImage, l.letterRectangle.getX(), l.letterRectangle.getY()));
    //...
    }
}
```